# Slowness with SQL Server View

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Here is my problem, I need to fetch some large record from various tables; to be exact, it consists of 30 tables. I did the join for the 30 tables, and it took 20 min just to fetch 200 rows.

I was thinking of creating a stored procedure to do some transactional DB call to fetch bit by bit of data and store it to a new report table.

Here is the nature of my business process:

1. In my web screen, I have 10 tabs of questionnaire need to be fill up by   insurance client. Basically I need to fetch all questions and answers and put them in one row
2. The problem is, my client won't finish all the 10 tabs in one day, they might finish all the tabs in 3 days max
3. Initially I want to put a trigger for insert on the primary table and fetch all and put in a reporting table. But I only can get record for t+0, not t+1 or t+n. How am I going to update the same row if user updated another tab at another day?

To simplify my requirement, I have 10 tabs of questionnaire and to make it simpler for discussion, each tab has its own table. And to complete all the questionnaire doesn't required you to finish it in one day.

How am I going to fetch all the data using transactional SQL in a stored procedure?

Comment: As far as I can tell, you're asking two things here: 1. How can you allow a client to save their 'state' in a web app. 2.How can you increase performance in a select query. I guess you already have an existing schema for this? No one can help without some idea of your schema. I suggest you break this up into a couple of different questions because web application development and SQL Server performance are very different topics

Comment: for the state in the web is not my concern, how they perform it not under my scope. im just doing a report to fetch data every week. my existing schema consist of 30 table, should i post my sql view?

Comment: If you have a report that only run every week, then as you suggest, the most straightforward thing to do is pre-dump it in to a table for reporting, as it appears that it doesn't need to be realtime.

Comment: yeah was thinking of this, everytime i run my SP i will truncated my table first

Comment: Do you have appropriate Indexes??? This is the most important thing when doing many joins like this. For example if they all join on UserId, then you should have an index on UserId on EVERY TABLE in the join?

Comment: yeah, i did run the execution plan, and added the indexes based on what suggested by sql server